# F#: Get length of tuple

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Is there any way to get tuple length.
I mean for something like let `a=(1,2,3)`. I must get `3`.

I have used the following code to convert a tuple to a list and tried to get the length of the list, but the result has `option` type and I cannot work with it.

```
let tupleToList t = 
    if Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple(t.GetType()) 
        then Some (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields t |> Array.toList)
        else None
```

Comment: A simple solution with the current approach (regardless of it may be the best) is to eliminate or unwrap the 'option' that is being introduced; either there (eg. return a 0 or -1 for a non-tuple, or the length of the list otherwise) or at the usage site (eg. treat it like any option that 'may or may not represent a list').

Comment: first the *length* of the tuple is implicite in it's type - that's one reason why you cannot get an function like this without reflection *trickery* (or some other runtime cheating ;)) - but in this case a simple `tupleToList >> Option.map (List.length)` would give you `Some l` fo a tuple of length `l` and `None` if your input to this function is not an tuple.

Answer (score 3):

If your intent is just to get a length of tuple for any tuple argument and some distinguishable other number like `0` for non-tuple arguments, then there is no  need to bother with converting tuple to list altogether; direct

```
let tupleLength t =
    if Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple(t.GetType()) 
    then (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields t |> Array.length)
    else 0
```

gives you such signature: `tupleLength: t:'a -> int`.

Testing it in FSI:

```
> (1,'a',10.0) |> tupleLength;;
val it : int = 3

> ("a",["b";"c";"d"]) |> tupleLength;;
val it : int = 2
```

but

```
["a","b","c","d"] |> tupleLength;;
val it : int = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

As given here, the `tupleToList` function returns `obj list option`, so you're going to have to deal with the `None` case.

What length should a non-tuple have?

For the sake of argument, let's set that length to `0`. In that case, you can get the length of your tuples (and other values) using [Option.map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340461) and [Option.fold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353802). Examples:

```
> (1, "2") |> tupleToList |> Option.map List.length |> Option.fold (+) 0;;
val it : int = 2

> ("1", 2, 3.0) |> tupleToList |> Option.map List.length |> Option.fold (+) 0;;
val it : int = 3

> "Not a tuple" |> tupleToList |> Option.map List.length |> Option.fold (+) 0;;
val it : int = 0
```

If you will, you can bind the expression `Option.map List.length |> Option.fold (+) 0` to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its always tuples sent in I think the following is simpler.

```
let t = 1,2,3


let inline countTuples t = 
 t.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Length

countTuples t
//val it : int = 3

let a = 4

countTuples a
//val it : int = 0

let list = ["4", "5"]

countTuples list
//val it : int = 1
```

If not always tuples, and may have generic arguments (last example), then a check for tuple is necessary of course...